# How to align an image in the center in WKWebView objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview, wkwebview

Here is my code to display image.

```
NSString *doc = @"http://13.232.1.87:3000/images/flights/bc4952c8ec51588cdbd72d91c4e1533562273837.jpeg";

WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:doc]];

[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: have you tried to answer to this question first: _how can I align an image in a webpage_?

Answer (score 0):

I see your link points to a simple jpg image.
You might then feed the WKWebView with html code instead of the direct link to the image, using

```
[webView  loadHTMLString:@"<html>...</html>" baseURL:nil];
```

[edit] Or, if the link is always pointing to an image, you can consider not even using the WKWebView replacing it with a UIImage:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:doc];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

or, for shortness:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:doc]]];
```

And then set the image frame (or constraints) like you would with the WKWebView